# cURL'ing a Phoenix socket

Tags: sockets, curl, elixir, phoenix-framework, channel

Is there a way to curl (or something similar) a phoenix socket?

Let's say my server is running on localhost:4000, and my endpoint has:

```
defmodule MyApp.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :my_app

  socket "/socket", MyApp.UserSocket
```

I have a UserSocket module with a connect method.  What can I run from the command line to connect to this socket?

Answer (score 1):

cURL supports by default long polling. You don't have to add any flags, just hit websocket url but you have to use http(s) not ws(s) protocol in url. Don't forget to add Accept and content type headers as application/json.

There is one drawback. You can't POST message to same connection :) so I guess it is better to use telnet instead and code by hand header to initiate polling so you can send (post) messages from same console. this way you can debug if "socket" is returning ok reply for your client pushes. and what is event better with this approach you can actually use HTTP 101 protocol upgrade to ws(s) :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what this command would look like?

Comment: Do you refer to telnet part?

Comment: Yes; since telnet is a better way to do it.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I think you should definitely go with curl. Just cancel it when you need to send message to server or receive message. So instead of connection to `/socket` you should change to `/logpoll` path. Simple configuration for you enpoint should be like this https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Transports.LongPoll.html

Comment: Telent could work, but you need to deceode and encode messages, which is very hard to do in telnet